# Odoo running on Docker permission denied for any write task inside a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, odoo, odoo-16

so we have a Docker setup for Odoo and we're running on Odoo 16. We have a bunch of custom modules and one of them has to create a folder inside of the module folder, create a zip file, and then write the contents of a user-uploaded zip to that created zip. But the problem is, it's throwing a Permission Error for any write operations (I think). Even with os.mkdir. I could get around the mkdir one by just manually creating the directory but for stuff like writing zip, I don't know what to do. I guess I can just skip the part where it copies the uploaded zip and use the uploaded zip instead but I would like to understand the permission thing. Frankly, I am not that familiar with Docker and Docker Containers. The container that our Odoo image is on already running in a privileged mood, I don't know what else to try.
For reference, here's the error when it tries to create the archive using  `shutil.make_archive(file_path, 'zip', file_path)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1583, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1612, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1810, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 149, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 698, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/om_export_import_product_image_zip/wizard/import_product_image_wizard.py", line 44, in import_product_images
    shutil.make_archive(file_path, 'zip', file_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 1063, in make_archive
    filename = func(base_name, base_dir, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 944, in _make_zipfile
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "w",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/extra-addons/om_export_import_product_image_zip/product_image.zip'

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (https://alpha.clicktheory.ca/web/assets/1904-01dcc54/web.assets_backend.min.js:967:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://alpha.clicktheory.ca/web/assets/1904-01dcc54/web.assets_backend.min.js:974:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user running the Odoo server has appropriate read and write permissions for the /mnt/extra-addons/om_export_import_product_image_zip/ directory. If necessary, you can change the ownership and permissions of the directory by using the shell:

```bash
chown -R odoo:odoo /mnt/extra-addons/om_export_import_product_image_zip/
chmod -R 755 /mnt/extra-addons/om_export_import_product_image_zip/
```

Replace odoo:odoo with the user and group that your Odoo server is running under.

ALTERNATIVELY, if you can access odoo backend:

Go to Technical> Database Structure

Under the "Models" section, search for the model name "ir.attachment".
Open the "ir.attachment" model and locate the field named "Store File".

In the "Store File" field, you can specify the file permissions for attachments stored in Odoo. By default, the value is False, which means that the file permissions are inherited from the operating system.
To change the file permissions, you can set the value of "Store File" to True and specify the desired file permissions using the octal notation. For example, if you want to set the permissions to read and write for the owner, and read-only for others, you can use the value 0o644.